# How to get the final counter from ImageJ MultipointTool to reuse it after?

Tags: python, plugins, imagej

I want to count several intersection on an image and get the final count to reuse it into an operation. I'm coding in python and I don't know how to get the count from the Point Tool of ImageJ. Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: I think you need to interact with the ROI Manager. Using `from ij.plugin.frame import RoiManager` you can use a command like `roi = RoiManager.getRoiManager()` then 
`roi_points = roi.getRoisAsArray()`

Comment: Yes it almost works but when I do this I have : array(ij.gui.Roi, [Roi[Points, count=3]]) and I don't know how to get the count from here..